# Does $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{i^2}{(3+\frac{1}{i})^i}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{i^2}{(3+\frac{1}{i})^i}$

I thought the only way I could solve this is by comparison after changing the 3 to a 1 which means it would converge. I tried ratio test and thought about limit test but you can not use that.

Comment: Do you mean for the sum to start at $i=1$? It isn't defined when $i=0$

Comment: it is defined, 3^0=1

Comment: No it isn't $1/0$ is undefined

Comment: yeah that is weird, but the question is with a 0 :/

Comment: The poser gets away with the $ \ i = 0 \ $ term because the limit of the sequence function is $$ \ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ \frac{x^2}{ \( 3 + \frac{1}{x} \)^x} \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .$$  It _still_ does look strange to write a series term that way...

Answer (score 5):

Hint: the denominator is bigger than $3^{i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{i^2}{3^{i}}$ will converge.  Try the direct comparison test.

Comment: and it helps slightly to write k instead of i to avoid confusion with the imaginary unit.

Comment: @GyroGearloose, true.  I just used $i$ because that is what was in the question.

Comment: On my first out-of-university job such a formula scared me to the bones (as it was presented at basic stuff) until I found out (about half an hour later) that it was just a traditional integer summation variable.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{(3+1/(n+1))^{n+1}}}{\frac{n^2}{(3+1/n)^{n}}}=(1+\frac{1}{n})^2(3+\frac{1}{n+1})^{-1}\left(\dfrac{3+\frac{1}{n}}{3+\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)^n\to\frac{1}{3}$.

Conclude using ratio test.